# Type of existing object all as string

Tags: typescript

I have an object type which has properties of different types

```
type ExampleType = {
  one: string
  two: boolean
  three: 'A' | 'Union'
}
```

Is there a shorthand way to explain this same type but with all properties as string?

```
type ExampleStringType = {
  one: string
  two: string
  three: string
}
```

In the docs I see some [intrinsic string manipulation types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html#intrinsic-string-manipulation-types) but nothing for setting all properties as string. I assume it must be possible. I was imagining something like

```
const value: AllString<ExampleType> = {
  one: "string"
  two: "string"
  three: "string"
}
```

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `keyof` to get keys of a specified type, and you can map them to `string`.

```
type AllString<T> = {
  [key in keyof T]: string;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
interface ExampleStringType{
 [key:string]:string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your keys and values can be any strings, you can use `Record`

```
type YourType = Record<string, string>;
```

Read more about the `Record` utility type [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type).